# How to continue executing to @Test after throwing an exception without calling @Test on exception method on Selenium Webdriver using TestNG

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

```
public static String driverPath = "C:/";
public static WebDriver driver;


@BeforeTest
public void Circulars() throws Exception  {

    ExcelUtils.setExcelFile("C://TestData//TestData.xlsx", "Sheet1");

    String username = ExcelUtils.getCellData(1, 1);   
    String password = ExcelUtils.getCellData(1, 2); 

    driver = WebPortalLogin.login(username, password);

    circulars(driver);
    option_list(driver);
    close_browser();

}

@Test
public void circulars(WebDriver driver)     {

    WebPortalNGFile.communication(driver).click();
    WebPortalNGFile.circulars(driver).click();

}

@Test
public void option_list(WebDriver driver)       {

    WebPortalNGFile.communication(driver).click();
    WebPortalNGFile.option_list(driver).click();

}

@Test
public void close_browser()    {
    driver.close();

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You want to [catch](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/catch.html) the exception. Although, if an exception is being thrown there is likely a good reason and you should do everything you can to prevent it and handle the error more appropriately than ignoring it.

```
try {
    // call your method
}
catch {
    // do nothing
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use

```
   for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    try {

      // call your Test method 
    }
    catch {
        // after catching exception use continue statement
     continue;
      }
    }

@AfterClass
public void close_browser()    {
    driver.close();

}
```

Answer (score 0):

In case you don't know where an exception can occur you can use **throws** instead of **try/catch**.

```
return_type method_name() throws exception_class_name{  
//code  
}
```